# Making a counter of repeating elements in a list and add it to a map ERLANG

Tags: erlang

i have to make a function to count all the repeating elements on a list and add said elements (with how frequent they are) into a map.
lets say my list is: [rojo, verde, rojo, azul]
my map has to look like: #{rojo => 2, verde => 1, azul => 1}
i have tried for quite some time now and im unable to come up with a solution.

Comment: Please show what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining @rorra and @Pascal solutions…

```
freq([], Map) ->
    Map;
freq([H|T], Map) ->
    freq(T, maps:update_with(H, fun inc/1, 1, Map)).

inc(X) -> X + 1.

test() ->
    List = [rojo, verde, rojo, azul],
    #{rojo := 2, verde := 1, azul := 1} =
        freq(List, #{}).
```

Comment: thanks for all the answers! all 3 were really helpful in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use a [map](https://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html), and by doing it, you can then go through the list, and check whether the map has the key being processed or not, if it doesn't have it, you create it with a value of 1, otherwise you update it by adding 1.

```
freq([], Map) ->
    Map;
freq([H|T], Map) ->
    NewMap = case maps:find(H, Map) of
        {ok, Value} -> Map#{H := Value + 1};         
        _ -> Map#{H => 1}
    end,
    freq(T, NewMap).

List = [rojo, verde, rojo, azul],
freq(List, #{}).
```

Comment: Instead of `case maps:find(H, Map) of {ok, Value}`, you can also do `case Map of #{H := Value}` if you prefer pattern-matching over function calls ;)

Answer (score 0):

Same answer than @rorra, but using the erlang libraries and anonymous functions:

```
1> List = [rojo, verde, rojo, azul].
[rojo,verde,rojo,azul]
2> Freq = fun(InputList) ->             
2>     lists:foldl(fun(Item,Acc)-> 
2>         Inc = fun(Count)-> Count+1 end,
2>         maps:update_with(Item,Inc,1,Acc)  
2>         end,
2>         #{},InputList)
2>     end.
#Fun<erl_eval.44.79398840>
3> Freq(List).
#{azul => 1,rojo => 2,verde => 1}
```

Just for the fun of fun. rorra answer suits better when starting with Erlang.